How can I create an FIR from difference of two impulse responses?
I am trying to create an FIR and associated waveform for a transfer function that is the magnitude difference between the two impulses responses. I have recorded both IR's but am struggling with getting the correction factor to be correct. Here is my code and results of the IRs and difference which is clearly wrong because it is reducing magnitude incorrectly. I can see kind of where it is going wrong which seems to be in taking the difference between them which results in the following magnitude graph and DBFS graph. I have included wav files as csv if trying to run.
EDIT: updated code to show my target curve and the resulting correction curve. I have changed the code to divide instead of subtract as suggested which got me the result I desired. HOWEVER now when I look at the time-domain FIR of the correction curve it looks really wrong and funky. time-domain plot of y result here is the new code that should work.
% Define the sampling frequency
close all
[x1,fs] = audioread('711_Tap1024.wav');
[x2,fs] = audioread('5128_Tap1024.wav');

Nfft = length(x1);
% Frequency vector (assume frequencies are normalized, or you need to normalize by fs/2)
f = linspace(0, fs, Nfft);
f = f';

%define Target Curve
x1FR = 20*log10(abs(fft(x1,Nfft)));
x2FR = 20*log10(abs(fft(x2,Nfft)));
targetCurve = x1FR-x2FR;
targetCurve = targetCurve*-1;

% Define or import the frequency responses H1 and H2
% H1 = abs(fft(x1,Nfft));
% H2 = abs(fft(x2,Nfft));
H1 = fft(x1,Nfft);
H2 = fft(x2,Nfft);

% Compute the difference in frequency responses divide
%H_diff = H1-H2;
H_diff = H2./H1;

% Inverse FFT to obtain the impulse response
y = real(ifft(H_diff,Nfft));

% Normalize the impulse response
y = 0.99*y/max(abs(y));

% Save the impulse response as a WAV file
audiowrite('impulse_response_diff.wav', y, fs);

% Plot the impulse response (optional)
figure;
plot(y)

% plot result of y
y_new=abs(fft(y,Nfft));
y_new= 20*log10(y_new);

figure
plot(f(1:Nfft/2), x1FR(1:Nfft/2));
hold on
plot(f(1:Nfft/2), x2FR(1:Nfft/2));
hold on
plot(f(1:Nfft/2), targetCurve(1:Nfft/2));
hold on
plot(f(1:Nfft/2), y_new(1:Nfft/2));

xlim([20 20000])
xticks([100 1000 10000])
grid on
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')
xlabel ('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel ('Magnitude');
legend('H1', 'H2', 'Target Curve','Correction Curve')


This is matlab, right?  You should tag it.

this might be better asked on the [dsp.se] SE -- this question came from the staging ground

The Fourier Transform and its inverse is linear. That means that x-y = ifft(fft(x) - fft(y). So I am not sure what the idea is here.

there's a matlab function called estimatetrf, if i'm not mistaken
